# How to search a string in files (not older than 5 days) that are present in a shared folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a string from among 100s of '*.LOG' files in a shared folder.

The code should search only the files which are not more than 5 days old.

The code of mine finds the string but it is searching first from older files rather than from the latest dated files. Moreover the below code of mine is pathetically slow.

```
Sub Loop()
 Dim file As String
 Dim Text As String
 Dim path As Variant
 Dim objFSO
 Const ForReading = 1
 Const ForWriting = 2
 Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
 Dim strContents As String
 Dim fileSpec As String
 Dim iFileNum As Integer
 Dim sFileName As String
 Dim TextFile As Integer

 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Dim fileStream As TextStream

 Text = Range("I3").Value
 'MsgBox Text

 path = "\\tests\test\uk\archive"

 file = FindFiles(path, Text)
 myExtension = "*.LOG*"
 myFile = Dir(path & myExtension)
 If (file <> "") Then MsgBox file

End Sub

Function FindFiles(ByVal path As String, ByVal target As String) As String

 ' Run The Shell Command And Get Output
 Dim files As String
 files = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("FINDSTR /M """ & target & """ """ & path & "\*.*""").StdOut.ReadAll
 FindFiles = ""

 If (files <> "") Then
     Dim idx As Integer
     idx = InStr(files, vbCrLf)
     FindFiles = Left(files, idx - 1)
     FindFiles = Right(FindFiles, Len(FindFiles) - 24)
     MsgBox FindFiles

     Dim FullFilePath As String
     FullFilePath = path & FindFiles
     Dim MyTxtFile As Variant

     Dim strFilename As String:  strFilename = FullFilePath
     Dim strFileContent As String
     Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
     Open strFilename For Input As iFile
     strFileContent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)

     Close iFile

     'Dim filePath As String
     If Len(Dir("H:\SIMD\", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
         MkDir "H:\SIMD\"
     End If

     filePath = "H:\SIMD\"

     'Dim fso As FileSystemObject
     Set fso = New FileSystemObject
     'Dim fileStream As TextStream
     Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath & FindFiles & ".")
     fileStream.WriteLine strFileContent
     fileStream.Close

     If fso.FileExists(filePath) Then
         MsgBox "The file was saved in the H:\SIMD\* folder!"
     End If

 End If

End Function
```

Comment: You're using `FINDSTR` in the first instance to locate any file with the string present. To my knowledge this function doesn't allow for date filtering. Perhaps a better approach would be to create a temporary folder somewhere, copy all files dated within your criteria into it and then run `FINDSTR` upon that..? Alternatively, you could consider writing your own search tool that picks up each file in the date range and searches it in some other way?